# How to Ignore certain Errors in Development Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

On a test system I have a lot of 404 errors that are not important to me right now. Still they are cluttering the console in Chromium's Developer Tools, making it pretty much useless.

Is it possible to ignore errors of a certain type? In this case, I want all 404-errors to not be shown.

Comment: This functionality doesn't exist currently in the devtools, but it sounds reasonable. Can you file a request at http://new.crbug.com/ and I'll throw it into the proper queue.

Comment: @MikeWest Is there a feature request template? If not, which should I chose?

Comment: There's not an explicit template for feature requests. Let's call it a "defect" for the moment, and I'll triage it into the correct queue.

Comment: @MikeWest I just submitted it.

Comment: Here's the issue for the curious: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113629

Comment: You can use negative filters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47423737/1704895

Answer (score 6):

If you need to filter errors for a particular domain, you can now do this directly using Chrome Developer Tools. Simply right click on the error you want to hide and then click `Filter` => `Hide messages from...`

[image]

Comment: There is no "Filter" for the current version of Chrome? Just "Hide messages from..." and it's not the domain itself.

Answer (score 1):

1. [image]
2. [image]

So for instance; https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVL0U.png shows the errors, all blocked by client with adblock etc, I want to hide "AdBar errors", so:

[image]

Basically:

1. Click the filter button, click errors to only show errors, then use the following regex:
2. ^((?!X|Y|Z).)*$

Answer (score -3):

I had a MVC web project a while ago, in the web.config section, I used to use this

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The customErrors tag that you mention is in the ASP.NET MVC's web.config. 

This question is in regard to Chromium Dev Tools.