# Is it possible to filter Chrome console log using a negated text?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Given console log output such as:

```
...
app.js:4408 update w/ model.location: Discovering
app.js:4408 update w/ action: Animate 911583 { width = 320, height = 480 }
app.js:4408 update w/ model.location: Discovering
app.js:4408 update w/ action: Animate 911609 { width = 320, height = 480 }
app.js:4922 some other log message
app.js:1923 yet another thing on the console
...
```

Is it possible to get Chrome to remove all lines that include the word "Animate"?

I've tried using a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like: `.*(?!Animate).*` (see also: [How to negate specific word in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240275/how-to-negate-specific-word-in-regex))  in Chrome, with no luck.

The regex has been tested at [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/):

[image: Regex tested at regexpal.com]

But it has no effect in Chrome:

[image: Chrome dev tools showing no effect from regex filtering]

Being able to just type "!Animate" or "Animate" [x] negate filter would be great. Is that possible, or can anyone get a negate regex to work in this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter the Chrome console messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130085/filter-the-chrome-console-messages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to filter out any result that contains the `Animate` string at any point in main string:

```
^((?!Animate).)*$
```

#### Explanation:

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?!Animate)` - Negative lookahead (at this cursor, do not match the next bit, without capturing)
- `.` - Match any character (except line breaks)
- `()*` - 0 or more of the preceding group
- `$` - End of string

#### Side Note:

Negative lookahead is currently broken in the Network panel, but fine in the Console panel. I discovered the issue when I was answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38524801/chrome-dev-tool-any-way-to-exclude-each-call-containing-a-string-with-regex/38525421#38525421) recently. I pushed a [fix](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=630852), awaiting review.

Comment: I tried your answer filtering a different word in my logs on Chrome 68 and it worked. However according to regex101 it should not. Example: https://regex101.com/r/L7sgqb/1. I generally trust regex101. What's up with Chrome here (or is it regex101 that is incorrect...)?

Comment: Worth noting that Firefox supports something similar as of FF 73: " when you perform a text or regex search in the Console, you can negate a search item by prefixing it with ‘-’ (i.e. return results not including this term)." https://hacks.mozilla.org/2020/02/firefox-73-is-upon-us/

Answer (score 42):

Since chrome 62 you can use negative filters in dev tools.

In the console filter box enter:

```
-<textToFilter>
```

I.e: To remove entries with text "Animate" just type:

```
-Animate
```

More info:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#negative-filters

Comment: Thank you so much. I am getting bombarded with DEPRECATED warnings as one of my core frameworks has recently updated and changed its policy. Almost every single major library is affected. I can now focus on what's actually important. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use :

```
 ^(?!.*?Animate)
```